# Actionscript 3 top-level exception handling

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, exception

Is it possible to catch ALL exceptions at some top-level in Actionscript 3? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [UNCAUGHT_ERROR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvents.html) event.

Updating to respond to the comment left by original poster, the event itself is available for both Flash and the AIR 2 runtime:

Language Version:   ActionScript 3.0
Runtime Versions:   Flash Player 10.1, AIR 2

Comment: @Fragsworth a.k.a. the Pokemon event...that's for Flash Player 10.1 though

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is possible to catch all synchronous and asynchronous events generated by AS3 code in one place.